# What is a field in C# and why would I use it?

Tags: c#

I am learning C# and I would like to know what is the use of a field in a C# class?

example

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Class_Constructor_II
{
class Fields
{
    const double RandsInADollar = 7.8;
    const double RandsInAEuro = 10.83

    public double RandDollarConversion
    {
        get
        {
            return RandsInADollar / DollarRands; 
        }
        set
        {
            DollarRands = value / RandsInADollar;
        }

    }
    public double DollarRands
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Fields f = new Fields();
         f.DollarRands = 14500000;
        Console.WriteLine(f.DollarRands);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx

Comment: Technically, your sample code does not contain any fields; it contains properties and constants.

Comment: Only if you replace `{ get; set; }` with a single semicolon, will you have a field `DollarRands`. Currently, it's a property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing better than the MSDN Definition:

[MSDN - Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx)

In case Microsoft decides to change their MSDN URLs again, here it is:

> A field is a variable of any type that is declared directly in a class
>   or struct. Fields are members of their containing type.

Comment: @Gabe - Which is why I added the quoted text. :-)

Comment: @JustinNiessner so a field is sort of like a variable?

Comment: @Matthew - Fields are variables. To be more specific, they're any variable declared directly in a class or struct. Kind of like the definition says.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you would use them to contain data that is used internally in your class. Something that needs to exist out of method scope for instance, with a longer lifetime, such as the lifetime of the object.

Making fields public is generally considered a bad idea - you would use properties as you have in your example. However, encapsulation dictates that the rest of the world does not need to know how your class does what it does - so it can use fields to store states and values that it needs to do whatever it needs to do.

Answer (score 0):

take look to this field are class wide variable 
[Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)